# Non-printable characters in reading word file in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, ms-word, non-printing-characters

I am reading a table from a Word file. Below is my code to read the word file:

```
  import win32com.client as win32


  word = win32.Dispatch("Word.Application")
  word.Visible = 0
  word.Documents.Open(SigLexiconFilePath)
  doc = word.ActiveDocument
  table = doc.Tables(1)

  for i in range(2 , table.Rows.Count+1):
    commandName = table.Cell(Row = i, Column= 0).Range.Text
```

All `commandName` has german characters and 2 non-printable characters in the end of the string. For example :

`commandName = Prüf\r\x07`

I used below code to remove the non-printable characters but it also removes the german characters from the string.

```
commandName = ''.join(filter(lambda x: x in string.printable, commandName))
commandName = commandName.strip()
```

Is there any pythonic way to remove the unnecessary characters from the string? Final output i want is :

`commandName = Prüf`

Comment: "``All commandName has [...] and 2 non-printable characters ...``" if that's always the case, just always remove the last 2 characters.

Comment: The reason for these characters: This content comes from a table cell. Those are the structural control chacters for the table cell.

Answer (score 0):

this simple line worked for me :

```
commandName.split('\r')
```